# how to write data to an excel file from a spring MVC webapp

Tags: java, excel, spring, spring-mvc, file-io

I'm trying to write data to an excel file from a spring MVC app but I cant seem to get it to work. my ExcelOutputer class works in a regular java application but when I tried to use it in a servlet, the file doesnt appear in my project folder. I used the same ExcelOutputer classs in a spring MVC app and it also does not work. I'm using Apache POI to write the excel stuff. Any help would be appreciated. I have added Maven dependencies and the jar files.

ExcelOutputer:

```
        package com.yrc.tools;
        import java.io.FileOutputStream;
        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

        public class ExcelOutputer {

            public static void output(String date, String terminal) {

                int rowCount = 0;
                int columnCount = 0;

                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Data");

                XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowCount);
                rowCount++;
                XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(columnCount);
                columnCount++;
                cell.setCellValue(date);
                cell = row.createCell(columnCount);
                cell.setCellValue(terminal);


                try {
                    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("Data.xlsx");
                    workbook.write(outputStream);
                    System.out.println(date);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Data class:

```
            package com.yrc.model;

            public class Data {
                private String Date;
                private String terminal;
                public String getDate() {
                    return Date;
                }
                public void setDate(String date) {
                    Date = date;
                }
                public String getTerminal() {
                    return terminal;
                }
                public void setTerminal(String terminal) {
                    this.terminal = terminal;
                }
            }
```

mainController:

```
            package com.yrc.controller;

            import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
            import org.springframework.ui.Model;
            import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
            import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
            import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

            import com.yrc.model.Data;
            import com.yrc.tools.ExcelOutputer;

            @Controller
            public class MainController {

                // http://localhost:8080/ReplicateTerminalShipments/main.html
                @RequestMapping(value = "/main", method = RequestMethod.GET)
                public String callMainGET(@ModelAttribute("data") Data data) {

                    return "main";
                }

                @RequestMapping(value = "/main", method = RequestMethod.POST)
                public String callMainPOST(@ModelAttribute("data") Data data) {

                    ExcelOutputer.output("date","terminal");
                    return "main";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Also please close the `outputStream` that you have opened.

Comment: I have and I cant seem to find anything. Is there any reason it would not work with a web application?